Find a generating subset of a set of binary vectors such that the number of even sums of generators in the set is minimised.
More precisely:
Let $S\in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ be a set of $n$-dimensional binary vectors, find a generating subset $G\subseteq S$ such that the number of elements of $S$ expressible as a sum of an even number of $g \in G$ is minimised.
For example, expressing the sets as the columns of a binary matrix then for
$$
S=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we may take
$$
G =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which satisfies the desired condition where there are only 2 even sums of these generators in $S$. Contrast this with taking $G$ to be the first three columns in which case there would be 3 even sums.
My work so far:
I have determined that, given a generating set $G=\{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$ and defining $n_{0,g_i}$ ($n_{1,g_i}$) to be the number of even (odd) sums of $g_i$ in $S$ (including $g_i$ itself) then one can reduce the number of even sums of generators by $d_i=(n_{0,g_i}-n_{1,g_i})$ by replacing $g_i$ as a generator with some even sum that contains $g_i$.
This does not minimise the number of even sums however and furthermore, it is possible to construct examples where one can apply this move and end up with a $G$ such that $d_i \leq 0$ for all $i$ but the number of even sums is not minimised, meaning you can't just continually reduce it through this move until you reach the minimum.
